# why import gym not working with python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

code

```
import gym

env = gym.make("mountainCar-v0")
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mazmc.png)
[conda environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRMhw.png)

[selected environment and installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjlnn.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw9bB.png)

all the required packages are install in the conda environment but still cant import opengym lib.

```
(gym) F:\pycharm document making folder>python mountaincar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mountaincar.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gym
  File "E:\anaconda install hear\envs\gym\lib\site-packages\gym\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from gym import vector
  File "E:\anaconda install hear\envs\gym\lib\site-packages\gym\vector\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gym.vector.async_vector_env import AsyncVectorEnv
  File "E:\anaconda install hear\envs\gym\lib\site-packages\gym\vector\async_vector_env.py", line 2, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "F:\pycharm document making folder\multiprocessing.py", line 21
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed()
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

selected environment and the installed packages are shown in the images.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Also, it looks like you installed many of those packages (scipy, NumPy, etc.) using pip, is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

you have a file named `multiprocessing.py` in `F:\pycharm document making folder` that has a syntax error.

you should not have a file named `multiprocessing.py` as that is a builtin module that you are shadowing...

Comment: yes sir that's the issue . thank you very much for helping me